# JavaScript Elementtree get all Elements between specific Elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, elementtree

I have a xml in the following format and want to get all elements between start and end. but the names are not defined or can change, so I need to get all between.

```
<startEvent name="Start"/>
.
.

<a name="something"/>
<b name="something"/>
<c name="something"/>
.
.
.
.
<endEvent name="End" />
```

Right now I use Elementree to parse the xml from String and find Elements. But I don't have to stick to it, if there is a better alternative.

Comment: Those nodes are not in `startEvent` node but just in between `startEvent` and `endEvent` right?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite something you want but maybe you can try this

```
const transform = require('camaro')

const xml = `
<startEvent name="Start"/>
    <a name="something"/>
    <b name="something"/>
    <c name="something"/>
    <d name="something"/>
<endEvent name="End" />
`
const result = transform(xml, {
    list: ['//*[@name != "Start" and @name != "End"]', {
        node_name: 'name()',
        value_in_name: '@name'
    }]
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Output

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "node_name": "a",
      "value_in_name": "something"
    },
    {
      "node_name": "b",
      "value_in_name": "something"
    },
    {
      "node_name": "c",
      "value_in_name": "something"
    },
    {
      "node_name": "d",
      "value_in_name": "something"
    }
  ]
}
```

This will not work if there are many node with name property. unless the whole thing you want to extract is under a unique node name.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like that, not super elegant but it works:

```
started=false
    xmlData.findall('./process')[0]._children.forEach(function(taskEntry){
        if(taskEntry.tag=="startEvent"){
            started=true
        }
        if(taskEntry.tag=="endEvent"){
            started=false
        }
        if(started==true || taskEntry.tag =="endEvent"){
            nodes.push(getElement(taskEntry))
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath might do it for ya! It's especially useful for this kinda stuff in python, maybe there's a JavaScript version.